# how to parse json response from google map api?

Tags: json, google-maps, java-me, google-maps-api-3

how to parse json response that we get from google map api and how can we show the particular location on map.

suppose i have entered one location name(i.e NewYork) and for that i have received json response,how can i show it on the map.

please provide help as i have never used google map api and json also.

Answer (score -1):

Whole bunch of examples here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/demogallery.html

My advice? Find the simplest one closest to what you want to do and view source.

Edit: missed the j2me tag. This advice is inapplicable. Sorry about that.